# C++ equivalent to Java this

Tags: java, c++, this

In Java you can refer to the current object by doing: `this.x = x`. How do you do this in C++?

Assume that each of these code examples are part of a class called `Shape`.

Java:

```
public void setX(int x)
{
this.x = x;
}
```

C++:

```
public:
void setX(int x)
{
//?
}
```

Comment: same, only because its a pointer you use a different indirection operator: `this->`

Comment: this->x = x;............

Comment: You don't usually need `this` for most operations that access members. Explicit use of `this` is fairly situational (e.g. when calling pointers-to-member-function).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Same word: `this`

Only difference is it is a pointer, so you need to use the `->` operator:

```
void setX(int x)
{
    this->x = x;
}
```

Comment: Not relevant, but I remember Stroustrup somewhere saying that making this a pointer in C++ was 'probably a mistake'.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. `this` as a pointer predates references; had references been invented earlier then `this` would have been a reference.

Answer (score 8):

The C++ equivalent is `this`, but there are a few differences.

This is a pointer to the object in question, not a reference; so, you must use pointer dereferencing operators before accessing fields or methods.

```
(*this).method(...)
(*this).field
```

or, using the more popular syntax

```
this->method(...)
this->field
```

Answer (score 3):

The C++ equivalent is `this`; that is, the keyword is the same.

Comment: Do not forget the `->` thats probably what the OP is missing.