# C++ version of java this. in classes

Tags: java, c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ equivalent to Java this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905598/c-equivalent-to-java-this)

What is the c++ version of java's this. :

```
class javaObj{

private String name;

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Only thing i have found that works in c++ is:

```
class cppObj
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    void setName(string name);
};

void cppObj::setName(string name)
{
    cppObj::name = name;
}
```

must I use cppObj:: or is there a this. equivalent for c++?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to name the parameter the same, but `this` is a pointer, so it needs pointer syntax.

Comment: Note that, as in Java, `this` is optional as long as the field being referenced can be unambiguously resolved (for example, a parameter or local is not defined with the same name).

Comment: Removing [tag:java] as the answer will not have anything to do with Java.

Answer (score 5):

C++ equivalent of Java's this is as below:

```
this->name = name;
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6905627/1055604) suggests an alternative syntax:

```
(*this).name = name;
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ equivalent is [the **`this`** pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this).

```
this->name = name;
```

It is more usual for this kind of operation to do the following:

```
void cppObj::setName(const string& name)
{
    name_ = name;
}
```

Where member variables are suffixed with an underscore and arguments are passed in by `const` reference (not copying the value of the `string`). There is no ambiguity here and the `this` pointer is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C++ has equivalent `this` pointer. the equivalent code is:

```
void cppObj::setName(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}
```

However you could enhance your code:

```
class cppObj
{
private:
    std::string name_;   // better naming style to distinguish class member with other variables

public:
    void setName(const std::string& name);  // pass by reference to elide the unnecessary copy
};

void cppObj::setName(const std::string& name)
{
    name_ = name;  // not necessary to have to use `this->` pointer syntax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like java, this, but "->" instead of ".";

- [IBM C++ for AIX: The this pointer (C++ only)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm#cplr035)
- [The Tutorial Site: C++ this pointer](http://login2win.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/c-this-pointer.html)